# Generic enum impl Rust

Tags: rust

I want to create a custom container, I've chosen enum over struct. My goal is to make  it have math capabilities by implementing Neg & Sub traits. This' what I tried doing but compiler requires further restriction to generic T, what am I missing so that the  code can compile?

```
use std::ops::{Neg, Sub};

#[derive(Debug)]
enum PolRec<T> {
  BTuple(T, T),
  Singly(T)
}

impl<T> Sub for PolRec<T> 
where
  T: Sub,
{
  type Output = PolRec<T>;
  fn sub(self, rhs: PolRec<T>) -> PolRec<T> {
    match (self, rhs) {
      (PolRec::BTuple(x, y), PolRec::BTuple(x2, y2)) => PolRec::BTuple(x-x2, y-y2),
      (PolRec::BTuple(x, y), PolRec::Singly(t)) => PolRec::BTuple(x-t, y-t),
      (PolRec::Singly(t), PolRec::BTuple(x, y)) => PolRec::BTuple(t-x, t-y),
      (PolRec::Singly(t), PolRec::Singly(t2)) => PolRec::Singly(t-t2),
    }
  }
}

impl<T> Neg for PolRec<T> 
where T: Neg,
{
  type Output = PolRec<T>;
  fn neg(self) -> PolRec<T> {
    match self {
      PolRec::BTuple(x, y) => PolRec::BTuple(-x, -y),
      PolRec::Singly(t) => PolRec::Singly(-t)
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let bt = PolRec::BTuple(6., 5.);
  println!("{:?}", -bt);
  println!("{:?}", bt-PolRec::Singly(6.));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this working, add trait bounds Sub<Output = T> + Copy in Sub impl block and Neg<Output = T> in Neg impl block

```
use std::ops::{Neg, Sub};

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum PolRec<T> {
  BTuple(T, T),
  Singly(T)
}

impl<T> Sub for PolRec<T> 
where
  T: Sub + Sub<Output = T> + Copy,
{
  type Output = PolRec<T>;
  fn sub(self, rhs: PolRec<T>) -> PolRec<T> {
    match (self, rhs) {
      (PolRec::BTuple(x, y), PolRec::BTuple(x2, y2)) => PolRec::BTuple(x-x2, y-y2),
      (PolRec::BTuple(x, y), PolRec::Singly(t)) => PolRec::BTuple(x-t, y-t),
      (PolRec::Singly(t), PolRec::BTuple(x, y)) => PolRec::BTuple(t-x, t-y),
      (PolRec::Singly(t), PolRec::Singly(t2)) => PolRec::Singly(t-t2),
    }
  }
}

impl<T> Neg for PolRec<T> 
where T: Neg + Neg<Output = T>,
{
  type Output = PolRec<T>;
  fn neg(self) -> PolRec<T> {
    match self {
      PolRec::BTuple(x, y) => PolRec::BTuple(-x, -y),
      PolRec::Singly(t) => PolRec::Singly(-t)
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let bt = PolRec::BTuple(6., 5.);
  let sl = PolRec::Singly(6.);
  println!("{:?}", -sl.clone());
  println!("{:?}", bt-sl);
}
```

Comment: Forgot to remove the redudant trait bounds but works well still